# How can I update regex to remove "HttpGetWrap|" from url?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Looks like there is a bug when using an interactive email form where `httpgetwrap|` isn't stripped out automatically. Until this is fixed I am pasting the code in an HTML template and trying to fix it myself. I want to simply update the regex in `SET @regexPattern = 'href="(.+?)"'` so that it will remove the `httpgetwrap|` from the url, but I have no experience with regex so nothing i've tried works.

how can I update the regex to achieve this?

code:

```
VAR @linkToClickCode, @link2C, @regexPattern, @trackedClickLink, @sanitizedString
   SET @linkToClickCode = '<a href="httpgetwrap|https://submit.mc-content.com" alias="formSubmit" target="_blank">Interactive Email Form Submit</a>'
   SET @link2C = TreatAsContent(@linkToClickCode)
   SET @regexPattern = 'href="(.+?)"'
   SET @trackedClickLink = RegExMatch(@link2C, @regexPattern, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [replace](https://ampscript.guide/replace) function?

```ampscript
SET @linkToClickCode = '<a href="httpgetwrap|https://submit.mc-content.com" alias="formSubmit" target="_blank">Interactive Email Form Submit</a>'
SET @link2C = TreatAsContent(@linkToClickCode)
SET @trackedClickLink = replace(@link2C,"httpgetwrap|","")
```